# How can I import Google sheet into pandas data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, google-sheets-api

I have a google sheet that I would like to analyze with Pandas, I want to set up all the codes to be update every time that I need to follow up on the metrics without downloading a csv.

Please let me know  what module I need to have in my anaconda distribution.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the gspread module.

A very simple gist with an example:
https://gist.github.com/sudar/9d8190486bf46bf3e3c3